# Load css and js assets as absolute paths during twig render

Tags: 8, hooks

By default, Drupal 8 loads css and js libraries using relative paths.

ie: /core/modules/contextual/css/contextual.module.css

However, because I want to generate static pages to be used by another consumer, how can I have all my libraries as absolute paths instead?

I thought of using the css_alter hook and my code is below:

```
function rint_css_alter(&$css, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
    
    foreach ($css as $key => $value) {
        $assetOriginalPath = $css[$key]["data"];
        $css[$key]["data"] =  "https://coaching.ddev.site/$assetOriginalPath";
    }
    print_r($css);
  
}
```

When I view the print_r result, it seems successful.

Result:

[image]

However, when I remove the print_r to view the page, I still see the relative paths for the css assets.

Note: When I used the print_r, I also saw the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.<br><em class="placeholder">RuntimeException</em>: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent
```

Is there a way to make css and js assets load as absolute paths? as in

```
http://example.com/core/modules/contextual/css/contextual.module.css
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me in a theme: https://ibb.co/v1BSmG1

Comment: @Clive not sure what the issue is. I just edited my question with my current result.
Would there perhaps be another option to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The folwing hook implemention will change the URL's to absolute URL's

```
/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 *
 * Pass the JavaScript array to the optimizer service.
 */
function HOOK_js_alter(&$js, $assets) {
  foreach ($js as $key => $file) {
    $file['data'] = 'http://example.com/' . $file['data'];
    $file['type'] = 'external';
    $js['http://example.com/' . $key] = $file;
    unset($js[$key]);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_js_alter().
 *
 * Pass the JavaScript array to the optimizer service.
 */
function HOOK_css_alter(&$css, $assets) {
  foreach ($css as $key => $file) {
    $file['data'] = 'http://example.com/' . $file['data'];
    $file['type'] = 'external';
    $css['http://example.com/' . $key] = $file;
    unset($css[$key]);
  }
}
```